# Async Storage in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I am working on mobile app by react native and in the test I saved some items in the async storage after that I extract release apk but my problem is when I install this apk on other device the item in async storage is still exist how can I avoid that.

Comment: Can you make sure you are not storing any data in localstorage when your app starts inside app. Check Inside your code May be you are calling your localstorage method

Comment: To add to @LSKhan comment. It is impossible for a package to keep the data of the async storage. The data saved inside the async storage gets saved outside of the APK package.